# AWS EC2 Crontab auto backup RDS MySQL database

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

In my EC2 Linux, I would like to create a cron job to auto backup a MySql DB in AWS RDS. I had tried to run

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u dbusername -p'dbpassword' dbname > /path/backup.sql
```

but I got an error

```
"Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'dbusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect".
```

What is wrong and how do I change the 'dbusername'@'localhost' to 'dbusername'@'xxx.xxxxxxxx.xx-xxxxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com'?

I had also tried to write a MySql script to download backup.sh but unable to as it cannot go beyond

```
mysql -u 'dbusername' --password="dbpassword" -h 'xxx.xxxxxxxx.xx-xxxxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com'
```

it is able to login but it shows the MySQL prompt

```
>
```

anything beyond that e.g.

```
> use db;
```

it will show

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

Comment: Is your requirement to backup the RDS db instance or to do a ETL job to a database running inside EC2 instance?

Comment: My requirement is to do a cron job in EC2 to backup a database running in RDS @Ashan

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump -u dbusername -p'dbpassword' -h hostname.here.com dbname > /path/backup.sql`

The same `-h` works for all mysql* commands, e.g. if you want to connect to RDB:

`mysqldump -u user -p'pass' -h db.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com dbname`